# php - merger array keeping values from arr1 where duplicate

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have 2 arrays `arr1` and `arr2`. I would like to merge them without duplicating or overwriting array values in `arr1`.

```
arr1
(
    [0] => Array (
    [aName] => Doe jones
    [ref] => 3
    [afield] => 01-06-2015
    )

    [1] => Array (
    [aName] => John doe
    [ref] => 5
    [afield] => 01-10-2015
    )

    [2] => Array (
    [aName] => Peter Griffin
    [ref] => 7
    [afield]
    )

)
arr2
(
    [0] => Array (
    [aName] => Doe jones
    [ref] => null
    [afield] => null
    )

    [1] => Array (
    [aName] => John doe
    [ref] => null
    [afield] => null
    )

    [2] => Array (
    [aName] => Peter Griffin
    [ref] => null
    [afield] => null
    )

    [3] => Array (
    [aName] => Stuart Griffin
    [ref] => null
    [afield] => null
    )

)
```

Desired output:

```
newArr
(
    [0] => Array (
    [aName] => Doe jones
    [ref] => 3
    [afield] => 01-06-2015
    )

    [1] => Array (
    [aName] => John doe
    [ref] => 5
    [afield] => 01-10-2015
    )

    [2] => Array (
    [aName] => Peter Griffin
    [ref] => 7
    [afield]
    )

    [3] => Array (
    [aName] => Stuart Griffin
    [ref] => null
    [afield] => null
    )

)
```

I have managed to accomplish this through a series of nested foreach loops and `if` statements. However this seems like a very inefficient way of carrying out this task.

I thought the following combination of functions would work, but it does not have the desired result

`$newArray = array_unique(array_merge($arr1, $arr2));`

Comment: You cannot use that kind of methods to do what you want because you have some functional rules like merge the items with the same names and not null values erase null values. `array_merge` and `array_unique` cannot be aware of that rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use that kind of methods to do what you want because you have some functional rules like merge the items with the same names and not null values erase null values. array_merge and array_unique cannot be aware of that rules.

You can use that kind of function:

```
function mergeArray(array $arr1, array $arr2) {
    $mergedArray = array();

    foreach ($arr1 as $item1) {
        $mergedArray[$item1['aName']] = $item1;
    }

    foreach ($arr2 as $item2) {
        if (!isset($mergedArray[$item2['aName']]) {
            $mergedArray[$item2['aName']] = $item2;
        } else {
            $item = $mergedArray[$item2['aName']];
            foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
                if (null === $value && isset($item2[$key])) {
                    $mergedArray[$item2['aName']][$key] = $item2[$key];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $mergedArray;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is more efficient than the nested loops that I had written.

Comment: Glad if I could help you.